# Compare Max Date from DB via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have problem with compare two date times. I have in my DB a lot of duplicate records and i neeed get actual data. I use for get actual data Linq Max().

In DB table i have time in this format :

```
2017-01-03 09:19:21.220
```

And when i try to use LINQ for filtering actual data

```
.Where(y=> y.EditDate == DB.Table.Max(q => q.EditDate.Value))
```

if i try get MaxDate to separate var

```
var maxDate = DB.Table.Max(q => q.EditDate);
```

i got date in this format

```
03/01/2017 09:19:21
```

How can i solved this problem, because Linq Max() not returns mili and micro seconds if i'm not mistaken.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're mistaken. You don't get datetimes back in *any* format, you get them back as datetimes. Most likely whatever tool you used to display that last datetime in your question didn't output the fractional seconds. Please verify how you obtained that text.

Comment: I break it in Visual Studio. In properties i see miliseconds, but why this expresion not working ?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't actually said that it doesn't work, you just said that this is the result I seem to get and it seems to be missing fractional seconds, **unless I'm mistaken**. Can you please **verify** that you **actually** have a problem?

Comment: Oh sorry. I have in DB a lot of data, and i need get actual data from the newest Edit Date. And if i used this condition, it not returns any data.

Comment: Please figure out exactly how many rows you expect from your database, do an `.OrderByDescending(...).Take(X)` to grab all those rows, grab the editvalue field and do a `.Ticks` on each to grab the exact tick value from each datetime. You're asking for more precision but I suspect that you have *too much* precision, in that the datetime values aren't actually identical, but they *look* identical.

Answer (score 0):

The var `maxDate` actually stores the millisecond, but the display in debugger uses the format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` without `.fff`

Try `maxDate.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff')` in the watch.

Comment: You're right. In properties i see milliseconds. But "Where" expression, where i compare two same date times not return any data.

Comment: @tomas Instead of solving the comparison, I I will just use `.OrderByDescending(y => y.EditDate).Take(1);` if you just need one record

Comment: That's a problem, i need more values and it is variable.